# Selecting k objects out of n without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have n objects, with "a" objects of type 1 and "b" objects of type 2. These are the only two types so a+b = n. Suppose we pick k objects out of these n, k<n, and we are interested in some probability, for example that so and so many out of those k picked are of type a.
My question is, what is the theoretical difference, if any, between taking all k objects out at once, and picking k objects one after the other without replacement. I am not able to algebraically justify that there is no difference, and not able to theoretically understand why there would be a difference.

Comment: There is no difference, except that when you pick one by one you can talk about the order in which they are picked (e.g. first object is of type 1 and the second one of type 2, etc).

Comment: As for a theoretical explanation of why there is no difference, consider the "shepherd's principle."  As an analogy, consider a shepherd with a flock of sheep.  The sheep are too fluffy and their heads are obscured so the shepherd can not count the bodies/heads directly.  He can however bend down and clearly count each of the legs of the sheep.  He knows every sheep has exactly four legs.  So, he counts the total number of legs in his flock and divides the result by four to see the number of sheep in his flock.

Comment: The generalization of this is that if you are counting arrangements and you have difficulty avoiding overcounting, if every distinct outcome was counted exactly $y$ times then you may correct your overcount by dividing by $y$.  Here, every overcount was counted $\binom{k}{c}$ times or $k!$ times or however you are formalizing the problem.  You will find that the overcounting that occurred going from picking in sequence to picking simultaneously, you will have overcounted both the numerator and the denominator by the same amount in the same way.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah now I see where I was going wrong with my algebra. At least my intuition was correct. I guess that's something.